# React Native AsyncStorage getItem returns promise not value

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, asyncstorage

I have a login form and I am able to post the form values. After the successful POST request, I get authentication token returned from the API. I need to save this token for future reference in local storage. For saving this auth token I am using AsyncStorage. I used `AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, responseData.auth_token);` setItem method to save the data.

If I console log this by :

`console.log(AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY));`

it returns as promise object like this

```
    Promise {_45: 0, _81: 0, _65: null, _54: null}
_45
:
0
_54
:
null
_65
:
"efcc06f00eeec0b529b8"
_81
:
1
__proto__
```

:
Object

how can I get the exact value from the AsyncStorage.getItem method?

This is my fetch method

```
fetch('http://54.255.201.241/drivers', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      first_name: this.state.firstName,
      mobile_number: this.state.mobileNumber,
      vehicle_number: this.state.vehicleNumber,
      vehicle_type_id: 1,
    })
  }).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseData) => {
    if (JSON.stringify(responseData.mobile_number) == (this.state.mobileNumber))
    {
      AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, responseData.auth_token);
      console.log(AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY));
      this.props.navigator.push({id: 'Otp'})
    }
    else
    {
      Alert.alert("SignUp Failed","Mobile number already taken.")  
    }
  })
  .done();
```

BTW in documentation they have used await. I tried using that but the pages are not loading.Here with attached the screenshot.[image]

Comment: Yes, just use `then` or, if you are in an `async function`, use `await`.

Comment: yes - use then or if you want: show your fetch call and we can try to help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

using Async/Await :

```
async _getStorageValue(){
  var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('ITEM_NAME')
  return value
}
```

Comment: This returns a Promise

Comment: No it does not, it returns the value. If you call `_getStorageValue()` improperly, then yes you get a promise, but that's not the fault of this code. This code has to be called by code expecting a Promise, so the call has to be with `await` or the follow-up code has to be in a `.then()` block, but don't mix `await` and `async` with `.then()`-style Promise handling.

Answer (score 9):

You have to call as

```
getUserToken().then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

Since this is an async call.

Comment: I think this should be part of the right answer too, because in my case for example I had my function defined as async but I wasn't using then in my call.

Comment: This should be merged with the top answer. I tried calling the function normally and was left scratching my head until I came back here and saw this.

Comment: yes, in other words _getStorageValue().then(res......)

Comment: No, blending `async` and `await` with `.then()` is a bad practice and completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually manage to get the Value from The Local Storage:

```
const getItemFromStorage = async () => {
  try {
       await AsyncStorage.getItem('ITEM_NAME', (error: any, result: any) => {
         if (result) {
           console.log(result);
         }else{
           console.log(JSON.stringfy(error));
         }
       });
     } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
     }
}
```