# what is the correct way to use promise in AsyncStorage.getItem method?

Tags: react-native, promise, react-navigation, asyncstorage

I've been trying to get the value in the AsyncStorage using getItem() method.

I've created one switch navigator. which is as follows.

```
export const AuthNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen, // Loading screen
    App:DrawerNavigator, //screens with drawer navigator
    Auth: AuthStack, // login screen
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
);
```

I've set **AuthLoading** as initial route. Below is my code of AuthLoadingScreen.

```
export default class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this._promiseHandling();
  }
  _promiseHandling = () => {
      AsyncStorage.getItem("userToken").then((value) => {
      console.log(value);
      if(value!=undefined){
        this.props.navigation.navigate("App");
      }
      else{
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Auth");
      }
    })
      .catch(res => {
        console.log(res);

      });

  }

  // Render any loading content that you like here
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

So, Initially I am checking for the value of the userToken from AsyncStorage. if It is there, I am navigating to App. If it is not there then I am navigation to login screen.

App behavior should be as above.

But when the app is loading, it always stuck at AuthLoadingScreen. I tried to debug the code where I am fetching the userToken from asyncstorage, but it is strange for me that control is going to the function  _promiseHandling but after that it is not going in **then** or **catch** block.
I've refer 5-6 examples to read value from async storage and handling its promise.

I've even tried following way but still it is not working for me.
[React Native AsyncStorage getItem returns promise not value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307769/react-native-asyncstorage-getitem-returns-promise-not-value)

```
async _getStorageValue(){
  var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('ITEM_NAME')
  return value
}
```

**What can be the reason behind this?**

Comment: `value` is a plain value - use it inside that function! The `async` function `_getStorageValue` of course returns a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
export default class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._promiseHandling();
  }

  _promiseHandling = async () => {

    try {

      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

      if (token)
        this.props.navigation.navigate("App");
      else
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Auth");

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

  }

  // Render
}
```

Make sure you have properly imported `AsyncStorage` before using it, and that you have access to device storage. Also, make sure your `AuthLoadingScreen` has received the `navigation` prop before you can call it.

If the problem persists, post the error here.